# How to show desktop site in mobile?

Tags: html, css

I just want to show the desktop version in mobile without any changes. I added the following code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" /> or
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

It works but not 100%.

Here is the screenshot for desktop and mobile.

Desktop Version
[image: Desktop Version]

Mobile Version

[image]

Can you tell me how to fix this issue. I just want to show the same like desktop.

Suppose if you can't find the issue in the screenshot i tell you whats the problem

"Dinner, Bridals, Gatherings, Festive Parties, Corporate Events, & Road Shows" is running under the banner in the mobile.

Thanks to all

Comment: can you give the desktop url??

Comment: thanks, here is the url http://nailtitude.com.sg/

Comment: you understood my issue?

Comment: The image is floating so text will naturally wrap under it. You don't see it when the window is wider because the content is not long enough for the "issue" to appear. If you don't want this to happen then wrap the image and the content in 2 different blocks

Comment: yes, i understood your point, but my question to show the exactly of desktop version.

Comment: +1 for comment from @Huangism. You're trying to do something that shouldn't be done, which is why browsers don't work this way. To do what you want, take a screenshot of your site and use that instead. (Please don't actually do that.)

Comment: @Shwan, you are the genius. I am asking something that which is can be done, and i seen few sites like that. I know to use it as a image. Thanks for your comment, my question is straight "HOW TO SHOW THE DESKTOP VERSION IN MOBILE SITE".

Comment: @SoundharRaj perhaps you have missed my point. Your site is showing the desktop version on a mobile device because your site does not seem to be responsive and therefore does not have a mobile version. The text is going under the image on the right is because the width of your page is too narrow so the content is longer. You can correct this by updating your code so the iamge and text are in 2 blocks or you can try to adjust the scaling `initial-scale=0.5` for example.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure how much it will help you.

generally in this case `"The image is floating so text will naturally wrap under it."`

1.Remove viewport meta

<`meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" />`

2. Add the class to the body
3. add media queries

example

```
.page-wrap { width: 80%; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .resp .page-wrap { width: 100%; }
}
```

Reference

http://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/